# Is there a sane way to visualize a division in "german style"

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations, tikz-chains

I need to visualize divisions in "german style". I managed to do it with TikZ, but it's a hard job!

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=going below,node distance=-2mm]
\node [on chain] {$\frac{1}{3} = 1:3 = 0,3333 = 0,\overline{3}$};
\node [on chain,xshift=-3em,yshift=0.8ex] {10};
\node [on chain,xshift=.5em] {10};
\node [on chain,xshift=.5em] {10};
\node [on chain,xshift=.5em] {10};
\node [on chain] {$\vdots$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=going below,node distance=-2mm]
\node [on chain] {$\frac{1}{7} = 1:7 = 0,\overline{142857}$};
\node (s) [on chain,xshift=-2.1em,yshift=1ex] {10};
\node [on chain,xshift=.5em] {30};
\node [on chain,xshift=.5em] {20};
\node [on chain,xshift=.5em] {60};
\node [on chain,xshift=.5em] {40};
\node [on chain,xshift=.5em] {50};
\node (e) [on chain,xshift=.5em] {10};
\draw (e) edge[bend left=60,ultra thick,->] (s);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Any idea how to do it without optimization "by hand".

Yes, I know xlop, but that's the french way

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**updated** added at bottom extension to arbitrary denominators. Also, arrows are a bit improved. No package used.

*moved from comments: the 12000/17000 case is hard to do economically. The code here does not see that the fraction is not irreducible, hence the real start of the period is earlier than what is shown in output. I don't think I will add extra layer for first reducing fraction. Same for 124/3072 example. Morale: apply this to irreducible fractions to get the real start of the period.*

---

---

<strike>No auxiliary packages.</strike> Well I use `xinttools` but that's not a package, it is more like a *mandatory* package. (bear with me...)

Actually, reading again, `xinttools` is not needed, just replace `\xintloop` by `\loop`...

The main restriction is that I am assuming the denominator to be prime with 10 so the period starts immediately.

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
% \usepackage{xint}% well let's do it with TeX numbers
\usepackage{xinttools}% but with some \xintloop, else where is the fun?


\makeatletter
\chardef\f@@r 4
\newcommand\GermanMaxSteps{20}

\newcommand\GermanDivision[2]{% assume A/B two integers with 0 < A < B
  % assume B is prime with 10, so period starts immediately
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=going below,node distance=-2mm]%
    \def\GerDiv@digits{}%
    \def\GerDiv@periodfound{0}%
    \count\tw@ #1
    \count6 \count\tw@
    \count@ \z@
    \toks@ {}%
    \xintloop
       \multiply\count\tw@ 10
       \count\f@@r \count\tw@
       \divide\count\f@@r #2
       \edef\GerDiv@digits{\GerDiv@digits\the\count\f@@r}%
       \multiply\count\f@@r #2
       \advance\count\tw@ -\count\f@@r
    \ifnum\count6=\count\tw@
       \def\GerDiv@periodfound{-1}%
    \else
       \edef\GerDiv@temp{\noexpand\node [on chain,xshift=.5em] {\llap{$\the\count\tw@0$}};}%
       \toks@\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
          {\expandafter\the\expandafter\toks@\GerDiv@temp}%
    \fi
    \advance\count@ \@ne
    \ifnum\count@ < \GerDiv@periodfound\GermanMaxSteps\space
    \repeat
    \if0\GerDiv@periodfound
        \node [on chain] {\rlap{$\frac{#1}{#2} = #1:#2 = 0,\GerDiv@digits\dots$}};
        \setbox\z@\hbox{$\frac{#1}{#2} = #10$}%
        \node [on chain,xshift=\wd0,yshift=1ex] {\llap{$#10$}};
        \the\toks@
        \node [on chain] {\llap{$\vdots$}};
    \else
        \node [on chain] {\rlap{$\frac{#1}{#2} = #1:#2 = 0,\overline{\GerDiv@digits}$}};
        \setbox\z@\hbox{$\frac{#1}{#2} = #10$}%
        \node (s) [on chain,xshift=\wd0,yshift=1ex] {\llap{$#10$}};
        \the\toks@
        \node [on chain,xshift=.5em] {\llap{$#10$}};
        \node (e) [on chain, xshift=-1.5em, yshift=+1ex] {};
        \draw (e) edge[bend left=60,ultra thick,->] ([xshift=-1em, yshift=-.5ex]s);
    \fi
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\begin{document}

\GermanDivision {1}{3}

\GermanDivision {1}{7}

\GermanDivision {13}{49}

% \GermanDivision {13}{14}% no 14 not prime with 10!... can not find period

%\GermanDivision{11}{13}

%\GermanDivision{23}{27}

\GermanDivision{13}{17}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

*updated answer*

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\makeatletter
\chardef\f@@r 4
\newcommand\GermanMaxSteps{20}

\newcommand\GermanDivision[2]{% assume A/B two integers with 0 < A < B
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=going below,node distance=-2mm]%
    \def\GerDiv@start{}%
    \def\GerDiv@digits{}%
    \def\GerDiv@periodfound{0}%
% EXTRA ANNOYING HANDLING OF CASES WITH B NOT PRIME WITH 10
\count@ \z@
\count\tw@\z@
\count\f@@r #2 % denominator (scratch register)
\loop
\ifodd\count\f@@r
\else
  \divide\count\f@@r\tw@
  \advance\count@\@ne
\repeat
\loop
\ifnum\numexpr\count\f@@r-5*(\count\f@@r/5)=\z@
  \divide\count\f@@r 5
  \advance\count\tw@\@ne
\repeat
\count8 \count@
\ifnum\count\tw@>\count@
  \count8 \count\tw@
\fi
%
    \count@ \z@
    \count\tw@  #1 % (current) numerator
    \count\f@@r #2 % (fixed) denominator
    \toks@ {}%
%
% this does not modify \count8...
        \setbox\z@\hbox{$\frac{#1}{#2} = #10$}%
%
\ifnum\count8>\z@
  \toks@{\node [on chain,xshift=\wd0,yshift=1ex] {\llap{$#10$}};}%
\else
  \toks@{\node (s) [on chain,xshift=\wd0,yshift=1ex] {\llap{$#10$}};}%
\fi
\loop
\ifnum\count8>\z@
\advance\count@\@ne
       \multiply\count\tw@ 10
       \count6 \count\tw@
       \divide\count6 \count\f@@r
       \edef\GerDiv@start{\GerDiv@start\the\count6}%
       \multiply\count6 \count\f@@r
       \advance\count\tw@ -\count6
  \ifnum\count8=\@ne
    \ifnum\count\tw@>\z@
       \edef\GerDiv@temp{\noexpand\node (s) [on chain,xshift=.5em]
                         {\noexpand\llap{$\the\count\tw@0$}};}%
    \else
       \def\GerDiv@temp{\node [on chain,xshift=.5em]
                                 {\llap{$0\phantom{0}$}};}%
    \fi
  \else
       \edef\GerDiv@temp{\noexpand\node [on chain,xshift=.5em]
         {\noexpand\llap{$\the\count\tw@0$}};}%
  \fi
       \toks@\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
          {\expandafter\the\expandafter\toks@\GerDiv@temp}%
\advance\count8 \m@ne
\repeat
%
    \count6 \count\tw@ % to identify period
% CHECK IF FRACTION IS A DECIMAL NUMBER
\ifnum\count\tw@=\z@
        \node [on chain] {\rlap{$\frac{#1}{#2} = #1:#2 = 0,\GerDiv@start$}};
        \the\toks@
\else
    \loop
       \multiply\count\tw@ 10
       \count8 \count\tw@
       \divide\count8 \count\f@@r
       \edef\GerDiv@digits{\GerDiv@digits\the\count8}%
       \multiply\count8 \count\f@@r
       \advance\count\tw@ -\count8
    \ifnum\count6=\count\tw@
       \def\GerDiv@periodfound{-1}%
    \else
       \edef\GerDiv@temp{\noexpand\node [on chain,xshift=.5em] {\noexpand\llap{$\the\count\tw@0$}};}%
       \toks@\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
          {\expandafter\the\expandafter\toks@\GerDiv@temp}%
    \fi
    \advance\count@ \@ne
    \ifnum\count@ < \GerDiv@periodfound\GermanMaxSteps\space
    \repeat
%
    \if0\GerDiv@periodfound
        \node [on chain] {\rlap{$\frac{#1}{#2} = #1:#2 = 0,\GerDiv@start\GerDiv@digits\dots$}};
        \the\toks@
        \node [on chain] {\llap{$\vdots$}};
    \else
        \node [on chain] {\rlap{$\frac{#1}{#2} = #1:#2 = 0,\GerDiv@start\overline{\GerDiv@digits}$}};
        \the\toks@
        \node [on chain,xshift=.5em] {\llap{$\the\count\tw@0$}};
        \setbox\z@\hbox{$\the\count\tw@0$}%
        \node (e) [on chain, xshift=-\wd0, yshift=+1ex] {};
        \draw (e) edge[bend left=60,ultra thick,->] ([xshift=-\wd0, yshift=-.5ex]s);
    \fi
\fi
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{multicols}2
  \GermanDivision {1}{3}

  \GermanDivision {1}{7}

  \GermanDivision {13}{49}

  \GermanDivision {13}{14}

  \GermanDivision{13}{17}

  \GermanDivision{12}{17}

  \GermanDivision{12000}{17000}

  \GermanDivision{12}{170}

  \GermanDivision{13}{96}

  \GermanDivision{13}{9600}

  \GermanDivision{3}{1400}

  \GermanDivision{1}{96}

  \GermanDivision{1}{128}

  \GermanDivision{123}{1024}

  \GermanDivision{123}{3072}

  \GermanDivision{124}{3072}

  \GermanDivision{125}{3072}

  \GermanDivision{125}{168}

  \GermanDivision{125001}{167999}
\end{multicols}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1269/is-it-bear-or-bare-with-me

Comment: @egreg oops... I had been asking myself but made the wrong decision. Thanks!

Comment: @jfbu Merci beaucoup! Time for a package to make german math teacher happy! ;-)

Comment: you are welcome; but then I would need to make it handle also the case of denominators even or divisible by 5. Will this be always be used with A/B and A < B ?

Comment: Oh,it's not for me. I'm not a math teacher. I'm just back in school after 20 years and 'have to' typeset some 'math' with LaTeX. This includes simple math with bases 2,8,10 and 16! ;-) But from time to time I see similar questions, so there's certainly demand. Of course, a general solution would be   desirable.

Comment: I am lacking knowledge in TikZ to get into the business of handling general denominators. I know what needs to be done but it would be too time costly for me to become nimble with Tiks nodes.

Comment: @jfbu This was a question for you ! I'll be glad to help with "Tiks nodes" if you decide to write a library ;)

Comment: @Kpym updated... but no library in sight ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't include arrows, but this can do a division in many different styles (german included): https://ctan.kako-dev.de/macros/latex/contrib/longdivision/longdivision_manual.pdf

Here's an image of the docs which you probably want:

[image: Image of docs]