# An English-style long division that supports decimal calculations

Tags: math-mode

So I like the `longdiv.tex` file to compute the quotient and remainder of two numbers, but as far as I can tell it doesn't support finding the decimal representation of a number.  The `xlop` package does exactly the right job but I want it in the English format, which as far as I can tell, it doesn't do.  I suspect the answer is no but my question is:  Is there yet any way to easily typeset the division of integers using the English style, and which will present decimals to arbitrary precision?

Comment: related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/423274/4686. Maybe you can adapt [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/423300/4686)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's `longdivision`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{longdivision}

\input{longdiv} % old by D. Arsenau for comparison

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\longdivision{100}{37}
\\
\longdiv{100}{37}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]